# Audio Public address system in java

Tags: java, audio, streaming, client-server

I am attempting to create a one way audio public address system in Java whereas there is a server that is sending packets from a mic, and there are multiple clients that can connect to this server.

This should be java 8 on a linux machine, NOT ANDROID.

My initial plan was to use something like mumble or teamspeak however teamspeak has a ton of license limitations for my client and mumble has a library in literally every other language besides java.

I have found alot of things on here about using libraries such as xuggler however all the code and suggestions at a minimum seem to be about 5 years old so I am hoping there might be a newer way to do this.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: This thread might give you a starting point - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550514/streaming-audio-from-microphone-with-java.  The example there uses Java Sound, which is the basic library and it does give you a good starting point.  The best library by far for audio in Java is Minim (http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/) which has equivalent terms for all the classes Java sound and in a more convenient way.

Comment: This link also might help - http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:426HnD-VNMUJ:forum.processing.org/two/discussion/7172/echo-effect-with-minim+&cd=4&hl=en.   Its an implementation in 'Processing' using Minim of an input to output patch.